# How to get URL of incoming HTTP POST request in azure function 2.0?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I want to store URL of incoming HTTP request in variable. I am using `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME")` but it gives the URL of my azure where azure function in hosted.

Please refer below code:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
#r "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage"
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

 public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, CloudBlockBlob outputBlob)
    {
        var requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data =  JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        var referer = req.Headers["Referer"].ToString();

        data.Add("url",referer);
        //data.Add("url",Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME"));
        string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);

        await outputBlob.UploadTextAsync(output);
        return new OkObjectResult("Data has been received");
    }
```

Actual data received as below:

```
{"firstname":"Sam","lastname":"Smith","email":"sam.smith@gmail.com","dob":"1990-1-1","url":"https://xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/xxxx?code=xxxxx"}
```

Comment: The `req` parameter gives you access to all the HTTP request details.

Comment: `var host = req.UserHostName;`

Comment: How is "the URL of my azure where azure function in hosted" not the same thing as "URL of incoming HTTP request"? Please explain more clearly what you want.

Comment: @TomW Azure function is use as a API here which has a POST method. So, it receives the data from other web pages. And I want to capture that web page URL along with other data.

Comment: @Coke  error CS1061: 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'UserHostName' and no extension method 'UserHostName' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sorry I looked at the doc for .NET Framework here -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httprequest.userhostname?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Didn't see that yours is .NET Core, you should be doing this -> `req.Host.Value;`

Comment: @Coke I am getting this value as URL xxxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net though I am posting data from client's webpage.

Comment: That sounds right, if the site is hosted on Azure. What value were you expecting?

Comment: @TomW I am posting data from other web page for an example www.test.com/signup to azure function url (code of azure function is in question). Now, I want to capture www.test.com/signup as a client url. Is it even possible?

Comment: If the user's browser makes a request to a URL and then that site or API makes another request to something else (like an Azure function), there's no "automatic" way that the original request information will get sent to the Azure function. You can still capture it. It would have to be sent explicitly as part of the request.

Answer (score 0):

**Update 0823:**

Hey, If you still don't know how to get the url. You can take a look of this:

```
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    var referer = req.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
    log.LogInformation("Referer is "+referer);
    return new OkObjectResult($"");
}
```

[image]

This is the most basic code to get the url.The circle that I circled in red is the url that sent the post.If you still have some questions, please let me know.

---

if you want to get the incoming url in Azure Function httpTrigger, you can do like this:

```
 var referer = req.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
        log.LogInformation("Referer is "+referer);
        var host = req.Host;
        log.LogInformation("Host is " + host);
```

in your httptrigger,the request header have the host and the Referer,the host is the url of your httptrigger and the Referer is the url that the request comes from.

Make sure your request is not from https to http,otherwise the Referer will disappear and you can't get it. https to https or http to https is ok.

I have already try the question you ask.I send a request from a webapplication that is deployed on the Azure and send it to the httptrigger.Finally,I get the right url:

[image]

---

Comment: It gives me URL of my Azure function.

Comment: Does it gives your the url of HttpTrigger?

Comment: Yes it gives me url of HttpTrigger.

Comment: @JayDesai Can you update the code of your Question, and i will help you find what happend

Comment: @JayDesai if your code is still Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_HOSTNAME") ,the httpTrigger will gives your the url of the HttpTrigger because the host is where the request is sended to. If you want to get the url that the request comes from,please use the Referer.

Comment: @JayDesai Ok,i trying to test

Comment: Still not solve the problem? in my httptrigger there is no problem. If you want to save the url in a variable,the string referer is ok.If you still have the question, I suppose you to make your project cleaner ,you can only leave the code which is been used to get the url,just like:     var referer = req.Headers["Referer"].ToString();
            log.LogInformation("Referer is "+referer);
    return new OkObjectResult($"");      I use this get the url successfully.You can try to make your httpTrigger be simpler, and then you may solve the problem.

Comment: @JayDesai Only save the code that used to get the url and the code used to display the url. Don't forget you need to refresh the httptrigger. When you first launch the httptrigger,the url will be the host.

Comment: You can try for one more time.

Comment: I checked your image https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuTXu.png here you are getting azure website's url as referer.

Comment: I am posting data from other web page for an example www.test.com/signup to azure function url (code of azure function is in question). Now, I want to capture www.test.com/signup as a client url. Is it even possible?

Comment: yes, I have try what you say.When you posting data from other web page for the httptrigger,the referer in the httptrigger will give you the url you want.

Comment: @JayDesai Hey,you can take a look at my updated answer.I show you the simplest code to get the url.If you posting data from www.test.com/signup,It will save the www.test.com/signup in the variable and show you what the url is in the log.If you still have any questions,ask me.

Comment: You can see that the website is not the azure website,but the code still can get the url.That is because the referer is not based on azure.You can also use referer in other places.

Comment: This is what I got "Referer is https://xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Customer?code=xxxxxxxxxxx"

Comment: @JayDesai I also confused your question for a long time. But now I think of another possibility, maybe the www.test.com/signup is the same with xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Customer?code=xxxxxxxxxxx. When you first build a webapplication on the azure, the url is the latter. Then you deploy a domain name to the application. But the url to get to the website is not only the www.test.com/signup but also the xxxxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/Customer?code=xxxxxxxxxxx.

Comment: I think of this possibility because you said you meet this problem again, but in my side it works. I build a webapplication and new a .aspx file, then i wirte a form to send a post request to the httptrigger, the url is right even if i don't publish it to the azure.You can check it, this two url maybe the same just like what i guessed.

Comment: The 'same' I said means that if you enter these two urls in your browser, you will enter the same page.

Comment: When you configure your domain name, the original url will not expire, you can still access the page through the original url

Answer (score 0):

You can get the host name from the `HttpRequest req` object:

```
HostString hostString = req.Host;
string host = hostString.Host;
int? port = hostString.Port;
string fullHost = hostString.Value;
```

Comment: It gives me my Azure URL.

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head, I'd think it would be something like:

```
  var url = request.Scheme + "://" + request.Host + request.Path;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can obtain the URL of the request HOST like this.

First change the `HttpRequest` to `HttpRequestMessage` and then the below two lines will give you the host.

```
var context = (DefaultHttpContext) req.Properties["HttpContext"];
var host = context.Request.Host;
```

I have added my sample app with output.

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
        public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous,"post", Route = null)]
            HttpRequestMessage req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

            var context = (DefaultHttpContext) req.Properties["HttpContext"];
            var host = context.Request.Host;
            log.LogInformation(host.ToString());
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Accepted);

        }
```

[image]